# Is it possible to specify that a class implements an abstract class after declaration?

Tags: typescript, typescript-class

I would like to declare an abstract class and a class without declaring that the class implements the abstract class in the same file.

```
abstract class ExampleAbstractClass {
    abstract exampleMethod(): string;
}

class ExampleClass {
    exampleMethod(): string { return 'test'; }
}


// I would like to specify that the class does implement the abstract class in another file
ExampleClass implements ExampleAbstractClass
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=47&pln=2&pc=28#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgogD2AWwAdkBTAQXGjggGFV0EBvAKAVYWN0JIFliIALAPYATABQBKAFwJIUAJYA7AOYBuJgF8mTFGgw58RYrV2MWbDgZ58hYqTOiKljBFD4BXKAoQByCMUjeKgiamloA9GEIAJIIAO6CbsjCCMhyANbECBCCMgTEsHIAZgCeWfzAiAKZOvTCgv4IclzEeMQKlfyZoLJUSHQYigjACoJVUAiFciRM+s3G9E2Gre16nIbkPfDzYEA)

This kind of use case is possible in other languages like Swift with protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

**example-class.ts**

```
export abstract class ExampleAbstractClass {
    abstract exampleMethod(): string;
}

export class ExampleClass {
    exampleMethod(): string { return 'test'; }
}

export interface ExampleClass extends ExampleAbstractClass {} // NOTICE: usage of interface!
```

**example-class.test.ts**

```
import { ExampleClass, ExampleAbstractClass } from "./example-class";

const a: ExampleAbstractClass = new ExampleClass(); // works!
console.log(a.exampleMethod());
```

You'll have to use `interface` alongside `class` since [class declaration merging is currently disallowed in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#disallowed-merges). You could also [augment the module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) which defines and implements `ExampleClass` in separate files using `declare module "<path to implementation source file>" {}`.

Comment: Thanks that's interesting. I'm seeing though that this does not enforce whatever is in the `abstract` class definition. You'll see if you remove the implementation of `exampleMethod()` in `ExampleClass` there is no compile error.

Comment: @ebuat3989 I checked earlier before posting this and it did error when I defined `exampleMethod()` as a function that returns `number` instead of `string`. Anyway, this isn't a design I would use because it seems easily breakable.